# How to 'add' text to a file using a python function

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a configuration file called conf.py. When running a python program that uses it, I'd like it to 'see' additional text at the file, without actually modifying the file.

What I intend to do is to call a python function at the end of the file, so that when conf.py gets parsed by another program, it 'sees' the text that is stored in the string, returned by this function.

conf.py looks a little like this:

```
option1 = [...]
option2 = [...]

myFuncion()
```

where myFunction is something along the lines of:

```
def myFunction():
    f = open('MyFile.py', 'r')
    string = str(f.readlines())
    f.close()
    return string
```

When parsed, I'd like conf.py to look like

```
option1 = [...]
option2 = [...]

option3 = [...]
option4 = [...]
```

where these latter 2 options are contained within MyFile.py.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: "I would like to append, without actually modifying the file" doesn't make sense. You can't add to the end of a file without changing the file. (Also, consider using real config files instead of Python code; your life will be much easier.)

Comment: I think he's saying he wants a python script sort of embedded at the end of a text file so when someone reads the text file, the contents of another file get shown at the end.

Comment: What is parsing your file? A full python interpreter?

Comment: I mean, you can certainly use `eval` or `exec`, but it's going to have to happen in another program - the one that reads conf.py.  This doesn't sound like a good way to attack this problem - why not just have that "other program" look in "MyFile.py" for additional config parameters?

Comment: @Brionius Yes, that's what I was trying to get across. Sorry for poor clarity

Comment: To clarify, this conf.py file is being used by a program called Sphinx (runs using python) to make documentation. I haven't got a whole lot of flexibility with it, unfortunately

Comment: You want `option3` and `option4` to be visible to a human reader? Because you _can_ place code at module scope that will create the lists in the modules namespace.

Comment: read `file` parameters documentation.

Comment: @StoryTeller Please understand that python is very new to me. I think what I want is the second thing you're saying. I've edited the original question so hopefully it's clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by importing MyFile.py, the trick is making sure that python can find it. Suppose you have '/path/to/MyFile.py'. You can do something like

conf.py

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/')

option1 = 'abc'
option2 = 'def'

from MyFile import option3, option4
```

Comment: the only problem with that is that there's a lot more to this 'MyFile.py' than just a couple options, which would make doing that a bit of a hassle

Comment: You can also do `from MyFile import *`. I wasn't sure which would work best for you.